# Columns on Safari and iOS aren't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I've tried to use bootstrap template but it doesn't work correctly on Safari and iOS gadgets, my navbar is going outside to the window border. But it excellent works on another browsers.

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="hd-lft">
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(888) 010203-4567</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="hd-rgt">
                            <a href="#">example@mail.com</a>
                        </div>              
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
```

It looks like that:

[image]

How could I solve that issue?

Comment: Please add the styling code for hd-rgt and hd-lft classes

Comment: There is also an extra `</div>` in this code

Answer (score 0):

All working, u have 1 extra div and check ur resolution

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
           
            
            
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="hd-lft">
               <ul>
               <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(888) 010203-4567</li>
               </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="hd-rgt">
             <a href="#">example@mail.com</a>
           </div>              
       </div>                  
   </div>
</div>
```